# How can I send request to my mobile http server from other device in local network?

Tags: android, flutter, http, localhost, httpserver

I want to host a server on my mobile device and send request to it from my computer. Both device are in the same network. I use flutter `HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4.host,8080);` to initialize my server.
I can send requests to it by addressing localhost:8080 e.g. in my phone's browser, but I'm not able to connect to it from my pc while using my phone's local ip address that I found in wi-fi details on my phone. I can ping said address, but that's all.

Does anybody know why that happens? Am I using wrong IP, are there some android firewall settings that I don't know about or is it just impossible?

Comment: Do not bind your server to localhost. Dont bind your server to a loopback ip. Dont bind your server to 127.0.0.1. Dont bind your server to any ip address.

Comment: Ok but I have to provide some address for server to work. What should I do?

Comment: I do not understand what you have to do. Please be exact. My servers do not need an address to work. Why yours would? Be exact.

Comment: Ok, I thought `InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4` was what I needed, but It was `InternetAddress.anyIPv4.host`. Thank you @blackapps for pointing out my mistake.